# I'm trying to get Selenium to click on one object using XPath on two different pieces of text, but there's an error

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Here is my code:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Supreme®/Vanson Leathers® Worn Leather Jacket']", "//*[text()='Dark Purple']") .click()`

Basically, I'm trying to use two two pieces of text to click on one object. However, I'm getting the error below:

`TypeError: find_element_by_xpath() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Here's the HTML content of the website for reference:

`<a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/hfxyzecg4/e6ap8ojhd">Supreme®/Vanson Leathers® Worn Leather Jacket</a>`

`<a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/hfxyzecg4/e6ap8ojhd">Dark Purple</a>`

Any way to get around this?

Comment: find_element_by_xpath function takes only one xpath, you have given two. If you want to click on both add another find_element_by_xpath statement and then provide the second xpath.

Comment: if at a time only one of the `a` element is present then you can achieve this identification approach by using `text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `<a>` anchor tag in `HTML` refers to a link. You can click on any one anchor tag at any point of time.

In `Selenium` any find_element method like `find_element_by_id` or `find_element_by_xpath` will allow to accept only one argument i.e., that elements value.

Use the appropriate link you want click according to your flow and use that `xpath` in the `find_element_by_xpath`